# How to set http cookies from an operation of a Jolie service?

Tags: cookies, jolie

I need to set a cookie to the browser from an operation of a Jolie service, but I can't find information on how to do it.

I checked the doc at https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/protocols/http and https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/web-applications/rest-apis-publication-and-integration, but it seems the use case I presented has not yet been covered.

```
inputPort MyIP {

    Protocol: http {
    ...
    ??? -> myCookie;
    ...
    }
    Interfaces: LoginInterface
}

main {

    [login(credentials)(res) {
    ...  
    myCookie=???  
    ...  
    }]
}
```

I expect to see the cookie in the browser cookie store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reading and Writing cookies

You can use the `cookies` parameter, which maps cookie names to fields that are present in messages.

For example, `.cookies.auth_token = "token"` binds the cookie called `auth_token` to the field `token` in messages (both in reading and writing).

Here's a complete example where the `login` operation sets the cookie `auth_token` in the browser.

```
execution { concurrent }

inputPort Server {
Location: "socket://localhost:8080"
Protocol: http
  // Binds the cookie "auth_token" to the message field "token"
  { .cookies.auth_token = "token" }
RequestResponse: login
}

main
{
  login( request )( response ) {
    if ( request.pwd == "secret" )
      response << "OK" { .token = new }
    else
      response << "Invalid pwd" { .token = "" }
  }
}
```

You can try it by browsing http://localhost:8080/login?pwd=secret.

---

## Bonus: cookies with correlation sets

Using cookies like this allows for combining them with workflows, to program [process-aware web applications](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.scico.2016.05.002). Here is a more elaborate example with the following workflow:

1. The user logs in;
2. If the login is successful, operation `say` can be called at will, until operation `logout` is called;
3. The user logs out.

I'm using correlation sets below to track the session.

```
include "console.iol"

execution { concurrent }

type LoginRequest:void { .token?:string .pwd:string }
type TokenMessage:void { .token:string }
type SayRequest:void { .token:string .msg:string }

interface ServerIface {
RequestResponse:
  login(LoginRequest)(TokenMessage) throws InvalidPwd,
  say(SayRequest)(void),
  logout(TokenMessage)(TokenMessage)
}

inputPort Server {
Location: "socket://localhost:8080"
Protocol: http { .cookies.auth_token = "token" }
Interfaces: ServerIface
}

cset {
  token: SayRequest.token TokenMessage.token
}

main
{
  login( request )( response ) {
    if ( request.pwd == "secret" )
      response.token = csets.token = new
    else
      throw( InvalidPwd )
  };
  provide
    [ say( request )() {
      println@Console( csets.token + " says " + request.msg )()
    } ]
  until
    [ logout()( response ) { response.token = "" } ]
}
```

To try it, you can navigate to these links (in order):

1. http://localhost:8080/login?pwd=secret
2. http://localhost:8080/say?msg=Hello
3. http://localhost:8080/logout

References:

- Sessions and correlation sets: https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/basics/sessions
- provide-until statement: https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/basics/composing_statements#the-provide-until-statement
- The paper on provide-until and web workflows in Jolie: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.scico.2016.05.002 (open version: https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3712)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track The setting of the cookie is carried out via the use of the return Header information as shown by the [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).

To manipulate the response Header in Jolie you need to work on the .addHeader node of http port configuration
Here is my code

```
interface MyInterface {

    RequestResponse:
     login(undefined)(undefined)
    }

    inputPort MyPort {
    Location: "socket://localhost:8000"
    Protocol: http {
      .debug= true;
      .debug.showContent= true;
      .addHeader.header[0] = "Set-Cookie";
      .addHeader.header[0].value->cookieCommand
    }
    Interfaces: MyInterface
    }

    execution{ concurrent }
    main{
      [login(request)(response){
          //doing something to control my credatiol
          cookieCommand = "yummy_cookie=myCookieValue "
        }]
    }
```

How do you read this code

```
  .addHeader.header[0] = "Set-Cookie";
  .addHeader.header[0].value->cookieCommand
```

this part adds to the response header the "Set-Cookie" header that will have as value the variable cookieCommand; the symbol -> is a [structure alias](https://jolielang.gitbook.io/docs/basics/data_structures)

Now your variable cookieCommand can be set in any operation behaviour in my example is in the login Operation

```
      [login(request)(response){
          //doing something to control my credatiol
          cookieCommand = "yummy_cookie=myCookieValue "
        }]
```

The picture below shows the result of the call

[image: Response Header]

and this is the result on the browser

[image: Application Cookie Value]

Now let us look at how to handle the incoming cookie. First of all, we can define a new operation op1

```
interface MyInterface {
RequestResponse:
 login(undefined)(undefined),
 op1(op1RequestType)(op1ResponseType)
}
```

in the request type, we need to add a new node that will contain our application cookie value

```
type op1RequestType:void{
  .cookieValue:string
}
```

Then we need to set the match between the cookie value received by the Http inputPort and the operation input variable

```
inputPort MyPort {
Location: "socket://localhost:8000"
Protocol: http {
  .debug= true;
  .debug.showContent= true;
  .addHeader.header[0] = "Set-Cookie";
  .addHeader.header[0].value->cookieCommand;
  .osc.op1.cookies.yummy_cookie = "cookieValue"
}
Interfaces: MyInterface
}
```

the port configuration parameter

```
.osc.op1.cookies.yummy_cookie = "cookieValue"
```

is read as osc.(nameOperation).cookies.nameCookie = nameNodeInTheType

Let's look at the call from your browser

[image: Sending Cookie]

and the trace from the operation (**jolie --trace** )

[image: Jolie Trace]

Hope it helps